# ImagePicker PlatformException that occurs only on packaged build

Tags: android, flutter, debugging, apk, imagepicker

I'm building a simple flutter app, which needs to takes pictures. For that i'm using `ImagePicker`.

When built into an APK, an error is returned when `_getImage` is called:

```
"Pick image error.PlatformException(error,null,null)[...]"
```

When executed through `flutter run` on the same device, it works as expected.

Relevant part of the code:

```dart
class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

  XFile? _imageFile;
  dynamic _pickImageError;
  String? _retrieveDataError;

  void _getImage(ImageSource source) async {
    try {
      final pickedFile = await _picker.pickImage(
        source: source,
        maxWidth: 720,
        maxHeight: 1280,
        imageQuality: 80,
        //  preferredCameraDevice: CameraDevice.rear,
      );
      setState(() {
        _imageFile = pickedFile;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        _pickImageError = e;
      });
    }
  }

  Widget _previewImages() {
    final Text? retrieveError = _getRetrieveErrorWidget();
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    if (retrieveError != null) {
      return retrieveError;
    }
    if (_imageFile != null) {
      return CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        radius: 150,
        backgroundImage: FileImage(File(_imageFile!.path)),
      );
    } else if (_pickImageError != null) {
      return Text(
        'Pick image error: $_pickImageError',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      );
    } else {
      return CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        radius: 150,
        child: Image.asset(
          "assets/images/user.png",
          width: size.width,
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  Text? _getRetrieveErrorWidget() {
    if (_retrieveDataError != null) {
      final Text result = Text(_retrieveDataError!);
      _retrieveDataError = null;
      return result;
    }
    return null;
  }

  Future<void> retrieveLostData() async {
    final LostDataResponse response = await _picker.retrieveLostData();
    if (response.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }
    if (response.file != null) {
      setState(() {
        _imageFile = response.file;
      });
    } else {
      _retrieveDataError = response.exception!.code;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Background(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
              child: FutureBuilder<void>(
            future: retrieveLostData(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return const Text(
                    'You have not yet picked an image.',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  );
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  return _previewImages();
                default:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text(
                      'Pick image/video error: ${snapshot.error}}',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    );
                  } else {
                    return const Text(
                      'You have not yet picked an image.',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    );
                  }
              }
            },
          )
              //: _previewImages(),
              ),
```

[Error log (couldn't copy it)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F45Wb.jpg)

[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q8Ij.jpg)

Comment: I've used this code: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/image_picker/image_picker/example/lib/main.dart as a basis.